# Why are these windows on some airplanes red?

Tags: aircraft-design, boeing-737, windows, flight-testing, airbus-a220

There are some red windows on the 737 and the CS-300 as well. Why are they painted red?
[Source](http://www.airliners.net/photo/Boeing/Boeing-737-8-Max/2771977/M/)
[image: 7378]
[image: cs100]

[Source](http://marriott.airliners.net/photo/Bombardier/Bombardier-CSeries-CS300/2659427/L/)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A red/orange color is typically used to denote flight test instrumentation. Indeed, these windows do contain such instrumentation. Below you can see a similar window on a 747-8I flight test aircraft (note the 7th window from the nose):

[image: 747-8I]

And the corresponding inside view:

[image]

Comment: What is in those big tanks?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard, those tanks hold water, which is used to create different center of gravity/weight conditions for flight test purposes.

Comment: Makes sense.  Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 12):

The aircrafts shown above are test aircraft and the windows are blanked for mounting test instrument. The image below shows the inside of Bombardier C-series test aircraft, which shows the mounting of test equipment.

[image: C100]

Image from airwaysnews.com

Also, the screengrab below from [this video about C series testing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=edrbbwhW0Cw) shows the interior of the C series test aircraft with blanked windows with attached instrumentation.

[image: C series test]

Also, see [this](http://www.airliners.net/aviation-forums/tech_ops/print.main?id=133643) thread that discusses about the same thing.